# Trouble Submitting Quiz Attempts in Moodle 4.2.1 via cURL - mod_quiz_save_attempt

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

Using Moodle 4.2.1, I'm attempting to submit a quiz attempt via the following `curl` command, but it's not working as expected. I've tried various examples from ChatGPT and searched for documentation on how to use this API effectively, but I haven't found a clear guide on how to prepare the data for different quiz types such as multiple-choice (single correct answer), multiple-choice (multiple correct answers), true/false, ordering, drag-and-drop words into sentences, short answer, and essay questions. Could someone please assist me in submitting a quiz attempt, or provide a URL to a comprehensive guide that explains how to format the data for these various quiz types in Moodle?

Here's the `curl` command I'm currently using:

```bash
curl --location '/webservice/rest/server.php' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--form 'wstoken="*****"' \
--form 'wsfunction="mod_quiz_save_attempt"' \
--form 'attemptid="24"' \
--form 'data[0][name]="q24:1_:flagged"' \
--form 'data[0][value]="0"' \
--form 'data[1][name]="q24:1_:flagged"' \
--form 'data[1][value]="0"' \
--form 'data[2][name]="q24:1_:sequencecheck"' \
--form 'data[2][value]="2"' \
--form 'data[3][name]="q24:1_answer"' \
--form 'data[3][value]="0"' \
--form 'moodlewsrestformat="json"'
```

I am having below response with 200 status code, nothing updated in database or nothing changed in quiz attempts on moodle platform

```
{
    "status": true,
    "warnings": []
}
```

Any assistance or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "it's not working as expected" - what does that mean? Also, can you share the code involved?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am having below response with 200 status code, nothing updated in database or nothing changed in quiz attempts on moodle platform, I have updated question with response I am having

Comment: You forgot to share the code involved. If you didn't write any code on your own, maybe it's better to post this at a Moodle related site? Also, XDebug could help to step through the code

Comment: I haven't modified code by own, Thanks for suggestion on XDebug, I will try that. but I looking for some help on documentation or something available for this.

Comment: If you haven't written any code on your own, this question is off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: Beside the lack of code, i can't find this subplugin. Are you sure it's still up to date with your moodle's version? And then up to date with php 8.x ? Finally why use a curl method? Surely such a type of subplugin should have a task, then using moosh or one of the moodle/admin/cli/ scripts would be way more efficient? (like scheduled_task.php)

Comment: @NicoHaase after debugging, I got what data I need to submit to save attempt